# Azure Pipeline Maven task fails for unauthorized 401 error

Tags: maven, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have a maven task in azure CI pipeline , where i want to publish my artifacts to feed in azure artifacts.
I added a maven task with deploy as a goals and enable the authenticate builtin maven feed. But its throwing unauthorized 401 error , Can some one help me publishing my build artifacts to azure artifacts feed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I added a maven task with deploy as a goals and enable the
> authenticate builtin maven feed. But its throwing unauthorized 401
> error , Can some one help me publishing my build artifacts to azure
> artifacts feed?

[image]

Add the [Maven Authenticate task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/maven-authenticate?view=azure-devops) before calling `Maven task` to publish the artifact. The **Maven Authenticate task** can provide credentials for Azure Artifacts feeds and external Maven repositories in the current user's settings.xml file.

In addition: To publish package to Azure Devops feed, you'll need to make sure the 1.User Account you created the Service Connection(used in maven authenticate task) and the Project Build Service have at least **Contributor** role within the target feed.

Feed settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes that works, But is safe to keep the credentials/secretkeys in setting.xml?

Comment: @shubhamarya Which agent do you use, Microsoft-hosted or Self-hosted agent? If you're using microsoft-hosted agent, that's pretty safe cause all the data will be deleted after the pipeline run finishes. (Every time you run one pipeline, you'll get a clean azure agent, so no one can access the credentials in your setting.xml file). If you're using self-hosted agent, just add a delete task(CMD task with doc delete-related commands) to delete the setting.xml file.

Comment: @shubhamarya If my answer helps to resolve your issue, could you please [accept it as correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) so that more members with similar error can benefit from that. Also, we can then archive this thread for you! Thx~

Comment: Yep it works after using a setting.xml file along with my build.